# Excel and Word document In same PDF using Word/Excel 2010?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, pdf, microsoft-word-2010, microsoft-excel-2010

In Word and Excel 2010, you can save Word and Excel file as PDFs natively.

Can you combine a Word and Excel file into the same PDF using this PDF save functionality?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not familiar with any obvious way to do this which works seamlessly, but there is the basic way.

1. Open the word/excel document
2. Go to the insert tab, and select "Object" (i.e. insert object)
3. Switch to the tab labeled "Create from file" in the dialog which pops up
4. Browse to find your file and select it
5. Optionally tick the "Link to File" option to make the inserted file update with the original file
6. Make sure the "Display as Icon" option is **un**checked

The pro of this way is that it's very simple. The con is that it does not handle well inserting multipaged documents one into the other. If you are really desperate, you can split one document into pages (probably would be easier for the word document) and then insert each page seperatly to the other.

Answer (score 1):

I have used [PrimoPDF](http://www.primopdf.com/index.aspx) to create PDF files.  It will let you combine two PDF files into one.

Since you are using different Office programs to create the PDFs I would use Primo to combine them into one document.

Answer (score 1):

I do this using a third-party program. You can use [PDFCreator](http://www.pdfforge.org/) to print to its queue and SAVE the first file - then print the second to the queue and combine the two into one PDF.

Alternatively, some PDF viewers let you combine, delete, crop and move pages around within and between files. I've had a good experience with [PDF-Xchange Viewer](http://www.tracker-software.com/product/pdf-xchange-viewer).

Answer (score 0):

Further to the answer of `yosh m`, one can use PDF Creator to combine print-outs from any number of programs. Here are the instructions:

1. In Word (or Excel, or Sage50, or whichever document you want on top) print the document to PDF Creator.  When the PDF Creator print dialog comes up, click the `Wait-Collect` button. *The document will not continue printing, and the PDF Creator "queue" will remain on screen.*
2. In the next app, print that document to PDF Creator. Its print out will be added to the above queue.
3. Print from any additional programs, repeating step 2.
4. When done printing from primary apps, switch to the `PDF Creator - PDF Print Monitor`window.
5. Click the toolbar button `Combine All`.  Only one item will now be visible in the queue.
6. Document -> Print
7. Name the file and choose a save-to location.

---

Warning and Caution:

PDF Creator is a best-of-breed PDF printer, but the owners have sold out to the Conduit people. Instead of the installer version, get the **Portable App** version and unzip rather than installing.

Answer (score 0):

1. Print the Word document as PDF.
2. Print the Excel workbook using PDF-Xchang Standadard V6.
   Be sure the setting is Print Entire Workbook.
3. Check "Append to Existing PDF", then in the File name bar,
   choose the PDF file you created in step one.
4. Save.